# confirmation delete message box for an image?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

The scenario is when I click on the X image next to a record in the tour_manage.php, this deletes the record by which is executed by another php page called delete_tour.php

I have managed to add the pop up box to the X image and when I click on the X, the message box comes up saying OK to delete or to CANCEL. However, the problem is when I click on OK and/or CANCEL, both buttons delete the record.

Help please!

These are the 2 scripts I got. 
First script is tour_manage.php
Second script is delete_tour.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm() {

        if(r == true) {
            window.location='delete_tour.php;
        } else {
            window.location='tour_manage.php';
        }
    }
    </script>

<a href="delete_tour.php?tid=<?php echo $tid ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this tour?');" ><img src="images/delete  
logo icon.png"  width="15" height="15"/></a></td>`
```

This is the delete_tour.php script

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../config.php');

$id=$_GET['tid'];

$sql=mysql_query("delete from tour where tid='$id' ");
if($sql)
{
header('location:tour_manage.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: return false from your javascript handler

Comment: sorry what do you mean by this?

Comment: try putting `return false;` before `}` of your `function redirect(){`. I think it'll solve your problem

Comment: Indeed, your href is still `delete_tour.php` regardless of whatever button is clicked. Returning false will prevent the href to be run, and the window.location will run.

Comment: I think it is something to do with the onclick="redirect()" . I am not sure where to put this around the href="delete_tour.php?tid=<?php echo $tid?>">

Comment: how exactly can I put the return false script before the function handler? I never done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

```
    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this tour?')"  href="delete_tour.php?tid=<?php echo $tid ?>">aaa</a>
```

Comment: if I take away the $GET['tid'] and add the scripts you provided, and when I try to delete now by pressing OK button nothing happens. This is the same difference with original fault by doing this

Comment: Yes thank you but I have managed to fix it myself. See update on original scripts of what I have done to rectify the problem. Thanx everyone for your help. Much appreciated!